# Aggregate Records by Month

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, average, aggregate-functions

I have a table which I am querying as shown below. The table has a record for each day. I want to update the query so I can have the data broken down each month (Desired Output). Any ideas on how this can be done? Database is Oracle.

```
select SNAP_TIME, SEG_GB, DB_SIZE, FREE_GB from dbsize
where SNAP_TIME > sysdate -730
```

[image]

Desired Output

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically use `trunc()` and aggregate functions. Say you want the average of each value for each month, then:

```
select trunc(snap_time, 'month') snap_month, 
    avg(seg_gb) seg_gb, avg(db_size) db_size, avg(free_gb) free_gb
from dbsize
where snap_time > add_months(sysdate, -12)
group by trunc(snap_time, 'month')
order by snap_month
```

If you want to actually format the truncated date as `mon-yy`, as shown in your expected result, use `to_char()` instead:

```
select to_char(snap_time, 'mon-yy') snap_month, 
    avg(seg_gb) seg_gb, avg(db_size) db_size, avg(free_gb) free_gb
from dbsize
where snap_time > add_months(sysdate, -12)
group by to_char(snap_time, 'mon-yy')
order by min(snap_time)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This worked exactly what I was looking for.